# Why doesn't Wireshark capture management frames in promiscuous mode?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireshark, 802.11n, 802.11, frame

I am working with Wireshark in promiscuous mode, which is normally used to allow Wireshark to capture all the frames in the connected network.

The problem is that Wireshark in this mode doesn't display any of the management frames like probe request/response, association request/response or beacon frames.

Does anyone know how to list the above frames in this mode if it is possible at all?

Answer (score 2):

You will probably need to capture in *monitor* mode to see the management frames.